# Facebox problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebox

Excuse me could someone send me a complete tutorial or post a example about of Facebox as its documentation is poor.

My problem is that ajax request is OK but don´t show any popup with content.

Perhaps I forgot steps.

My code

Application controller

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  include AuthenticatedSystem
  include RoleRequirementSystem
  include FaceboxRender

...

end
```

Application layout

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
            "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>

      <title><%= configatron.site_name %></title>

      <%= stylesheet_link_tag "facebox" %>
      <%= stylesheet_link_merged :base %>
      <%= javascript_include_merged :base %>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'mobile' if mobile_device? %>
      <%= javascript_include_tag('jquery.simplemodal') %>
      <%= javascript_include_tag("jquery.form") %>
      <%= javascript_include_tag "facebox" %>
      <script type="text/javascript">
          $j = jQuery.noConflict();
          jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            $('a[rel*=facebox]').facebox()
          })

      </script>
    </head>
...
...
```

index view

```
<% content_for :header do %>Lista de Pack<% end %>

<%= facebox_link_to "Ver packs", :url => {:controller => "packs", :action => "prueba"}, :method => :get -%>
```

prueba view

```
<div id="pack-list">
 <h1>HOLA</h1>
</div>
```

packs controller

```
  def index
  end

  def prueba
    @packs = Pack.paginate :page => params[:page], :per_page => 5

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js { render_to_facebox }
    end
  end
```

Comment: Suggest that its your understanding of the documentation that is poor. How do you know the ajax request is OK? Something must be going wrong with it to not return any data. You will need to post code and examples of what is going wrong for anyone to be able to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as it says here: http://chriswanstrath.com/facebox/

```
<a href="remote.html" rel="facebox">text</a>

<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="/facebox/facebox.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="/facebox/facebox.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('a[rel*=facebox]').facebox() 
  })
</script>
```

Comment: thanks I add script tag in application layout but I cannot see the popup. I add css and js files. Also include in application controller the include code.

Comment: I can see the background style but I cannot see the content. The error is :try {
jQuery.facebox("<div id=\"pack-list\">\n <h1>HOLA</h1>\n</div>")
} catch (e) { alert('RJS error:\n\n' + e.toString()); alert('jQuery.facebox(\"<div id=\\\"pack-list\\\">\\n <h1>HOLA</h1>\\n</div>\")'); throw e }

Comment: that sounds like your rails action returns rjs (javascript) where it should return html. remove the respond_to block in your controller and make sure it renders html.